# Вопрос на засыпку. Массивы и json_encode

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.
Есть простая функция:

```
public function exec () {
    $arr = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 5000000; ++$i)
        $arr['a' . $i] = $i;
    return $arr;
}
```

Как Вы считаете, нормально ли время генерации и отдачи по сети массива, предварительно обработанного с помощью json_encode за 1.2~2 секунды ?

P.S. обратите внимание, массив ассоциативный.

Comment: у вас там что-то около 50мб, вы в курсе?)) Больше даже)

Comment: нормально для чего? вообще к чему вопрос?

Comment: Тестирую производительность. Передача осуществляется средствами сокетов .... с локалхоста по локалхосту.

И утечки памяти глядел... будут ли.. или нет.
Память вроде норм, а время меня заинтересовало.... быстро, медленно... хз :)

P.S. Процессор грузится на 10% при генерации этого массива и обработки json_encode-ом

Если кому-либо интересно - опишу более подробно что и как выполняется.

Answer (score 4):

Тестирование показало:

- Классический метод выполнения:

  Создание массива прекратилось критической ошибкой уже на 601099 позиции. Время генерации - 10.34519290924072
- "Демонический" многопроцессорный метод:

  Выполнение обрадовало. Всего-то 1.5~2 секунды на 6.000.000 элементов + передача по сети (мгновенно)

Относительно памяти.

- Стандарный метод (Апач + Браузер).... !!кстати, в браузер я ничего не выводил, просто создал массив!! нагло занял у меня всю память  и скушал 80% проца.... так еще и рухнул.
- "Демонический" - сожрал менее 15-10% и памяти порядка 60Мб. После чего память моментально была очищена.

Итого. Итог. Вчера там кто-то говорил, что демоны на PHP - это страшно? :)) А я думаю, что очень даже неплохо :)

Comment: Так вы добавьте своим демонам полную поддержку хттп(с)/фтп/ссл, кэширование вывода и прочие апачевские плюшки - и посмотрите еще раз)

А вообще спорить не буду, в консольном подходе при использовании только нужного оно приятные результаты дает.

Comment: А смысл добавлять сервер-сайду хттп(с)/фтп/ссл плюшки ? :)) На то он и сервер-сайд :)

Answer (score 1):

Наверно это нормально, если нужно быстрее, то лучше самому генерировать json.

```
$json='{';
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v)){
    $json.="'".$k."':'".$v."',";
};
$json.='}';
```

Comment: P.S. замеров скорости не производил

Comment: Дело не в этом :))) Я же говорю - любопытно было на счет времени. 
Я сравниваю работу PHP как демона и классический вариант.

Классика - педалит :(